# An error occurred trying to connect - docker when not using sudo

Tags: docker

I am on ubuntu 14.04 and unless I use sudo to run docker commands I get this error:

```
$ docker images
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://vagrant.f8:2375/v1.24/images/json: dial tcp: lookup vagrant.f8 on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
```

I have uninstalled vagrant, re-installed docker and still have this error. Is this some kind of baked in config that I haven't been able to remove?

Comment: What is your `$DOCKER_HOST` set to?

Comment: tcp://vagrant.f8:2375 ... what should it be set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$DOCKER_HOST` is used to tell the docker CLI where to connect for all commands. It looks like you've configured yours, possibly from a docker-machine setting, to a host you're no longer using. You can `unset $DOCKER_HOST` to send all requests to the local `/var/run/docker.sock` socket. Or you can configure it to match the value of your root user.

Docker can be configured to listen to 2375 (unencrypted) or 2376 (tls certificate setup required) with additional flags to the daemon, but if you have not configured these, unsetting the variable is most likely your solution. If you were using docker-machine, then `eval $(docker-machine env -u)` is likely what you want to run.